# Grouping ForeignKey Related Form Fields

Tags: django, django-forms, field

I have these two models

```
class Event(models.Model):
event_name=models.CharField("Event Name",max_length=255)
category = models.ManyToManyField(SubCategory)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.event_name

class Category(models.Model):
   category_name= models.CharField(max_length=255)
   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.category_name


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    parent_category=models.ForeignKey(Category)
    category_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

In my form.py

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=Event

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields["category"].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple()

    self.fields["category"].queryset = SubCategory.objects.all()
```

I created a an form of my model `EventForm` and the subcategories display as checkboxes just like I intended. The only problem is that, I want to list the subcategory checkboxes according to thier respective parent categories but am not sure how to do that. Can anyone help me on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a ManyToMany field for  rather than ForeignKey in `class SubCategory`.

Comment: The thing is that each `Category` Has many `SubCategories` but a subcategory can have only one parent `Category` . What I want is a form that will display a group of `subcategories` as checkboxes under their various parent `categories`. Instead the form just list all subcategories from the first to the last added.